# Display elements only when player is paused

Tags: javascript, html

I want try to display some information inside div content when player is paused, but problem is because this is displayed when player is paused and when is seeked.

I have create example:

```js
    var video = $('#video')[0];
    video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
 $('.text').text('playing');
     });

     video.addEventListener("pause", function() { 
 $('.text').text('pause');
     });
```

```css
video {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">test</div>
<video id="video" controls>
<source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you seeking you will see that player is change event to pause. Can't find solution to display something only when player is paused. Any idea?

Comment: @AndrewL64 While seeking, the `pause` event is fired which is what I think the OP means.

Comment: Video seeking also display paused that is problem, i need to find solution to display something only when user click pause icon or pause video, not when seeking videos. @Nik Kyriakides yes that is what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another event listener for `seeking` using the WebEvent [seeking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/seeking) which is fired when a seek operation began.

Check the Code Snippet below for a practical example of using the `seeking` event.

```js
    var video = $('#video')[0];
    video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
 $('.text').text('playing');
     });

     video.addEventListener("pause", function() { 
 $('.text').text('pause');
     });

     video.addEventListener("seeking", function() {
       $('.text').text('seeking');
     });
```

```css
video {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">test</div>
<video id="video" controls>
<source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: No I have already try but you can see 'pause' at the moment when you seek video.

Comment: Check and run the Code Snippet in my question. The "pause" text doesn't show while seeking.

Comment: Select speed 0.25 and check whats happend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5leg-dEhodI